# SSL Error while consuming SOAP based WSDL from Python

Tags: python, ssl, soap, wsdl

We were trying to consume a SOAP based WSDL service from Python and we are getting an SSL error as mentioned below. I downloaded the SSL certificate from the server and placed it locally and still it is throwing the same error.

**Error Details:**

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=,
>   port=50101): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   WSService?wsdl&mode=ws_policy (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown
>   error (_ssl.c:3053)'),))

**Code Lines**

```
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
#session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("USER", "PWD")
#session.verify=False
session.verify = "C:\\Users\\ID\\Desktop\\ssl-credentials.p8"
client = Client(
"https://<server>:<port>/WSDL/WSService?wsdl&mode=ws_policy",
transport=Transport(session=session))

# request_payload = { "Request" : [ ] }

request_payload = {
"Ref": "<value>",
"quantity": "<value>",
"Routing": "<value>",
"StepId": "<value>",
}
client.service.<WS>(Site="<value>", RequestContext="", Request=request_payload);
```